# ReactJs useContext with Typecript

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning useContext hook with typescript,
I face a problem where I have to use any when call the context, I still confuse while in the tutorial I'm following they don't put type there, I'm sorry I use image to show my code, I think it will more readable

*The problem on the top right panel where I use any to make it work for now

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUb9X.png)

Comment: They probably have aggressive type checking turned off in their tutorial environment so they don’t get bogged down by things like this. I wouldn’t sweat it.

Comment: Hi there, rather than a screenshot, can you either paste your code or add the key parts of the code to a sandbox? I have a hunch, but it'd be easier to either copy the code from your post or fork it from your sandbox. (the screenshot informs, but for helping out, having the code itself is better).